# mongodb restore multiple collections with single command

Tags: mongodb, restore

**How do I restore multiple collections at once in mongodb.**

I have tried

```
mongorestore -c Role -c UserAccount -c Permission -d movie-app dump/
```

and I got an error `file dump is a directory, not a bson file`

I can restore single collection at a time I have to  specify the bson file like

```
  mongorestore -c UserAccount -d movie-app dump/movie-app/UserAccount.bson
```

I need to know how do I ***restore multiple collection with one command.***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try these parameter to Include or exclude collections

- [--nsInclude](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-nsinclude)
- [--nsExclude](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore-nsexclude)

During restoration, you can ignore the unwanted collections.

EG:

## Dump all the collections

`mongodump --db bhuvi --out /tmp`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 20 18:09 ./
drwxrwxrwt 9 root root 4096 Dec 20 18:25 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  125 Dec 20 18:09 coll1.bson
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  125 Dec 20 18:09 coll1.metadata.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   83 Dec 20 18:09 coll2.bson
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  125 Dec 20 18:09 coll2.metadata.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  125 Dec 20 18:09 coll3.bson
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  125 Dec 20 18:09 coll3.metadata.json
```

My dump folder has 3 collections.

1. coll1
2. coll2
3. coll3

## Restoring coll2 and coll3 collections

I want to restore coll2 and coll3 in the test db.

`mongorestore --db test --nsExclude 'test.*1' /tmp/bhuvi/`

```
2017-12-20T18:25:50.299+0000    the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead
2017-12-20T18:25:50.299+0000    building a list of collections to restore from /tmp/bhuvi dir
2017-12-20T18:25:50.299+0000    reading metadata for test.coll3 from /tmp/bhuvi/coll3.metadata.json
2017-12-20T18:25:50.312+0000    restoring test.coll3 from /tmp/bhuvi/coll3.bson
2017-12-20T18:25:50.313+0000    reading metadata for test.coll2 from /tmp/bhuvi/coll2.metadata.json
2017-12-20T18:25:50.326+0000    restoring test.coll2 from /tmp/bhuvi/coll2.bson
2017-12-20T18:25:50.327+0000    no indexes to restore
2017-12-20T18:25:50.327+0000    finished restoring test.coll3 (3 documents)
2017-12-20T18:25:50.327+0000    no indexes to restore
2017-12-20T18:25:50.328+0000    finished restoring test.coll2 (2 documents)
2017-12-20T18:25:50.328+0000    done
```

## Check the collections

```
> use test
switched to db test
> show collections
coll2
coll3
```

## For restore collections with similar names

`mongorestore --db test --nsInclude 'test.coll*' /tmp/bhuvi/`

## Restore collections with different pattern

There is no straight forward method for this, but we can create a loop to restore this.

### create a file with list of collections that we need to restore

```
vi collections
#add the collections names and save.
coll1
coll2
```

### shell script for restore in loop

```
#!/bin/bash
input="collcetions"
backup_path="/tmp/mydb"
while IFS= read -r col_name
do
  mongorestore --db sqladmin --collection $col_name $backup_path/$col_name.bson
done < "$input"
```

`root@lin_sql1:/home/ubuntu# ./restore`

```
2017-12-21T04:56:36.596+0000    checking for collection data in /tmp/mydb/coll1.bson
2017-12-21T04:56:36.596+0000    reading metadata for sqladmin.coll1 from /tmp/mydb/coll1.metadata.json
2017-12-21T04:56:36.616+0000    restoring sqladmin.coll1 from /tmp/mydb/coll1.bson
2017-12-21T04:56:36.677+0000    no indexes to restore
2017-12-21T04:56:36.677+0000    finished restoring sqladmin.coll1 (3 documents)
2017-12-21T04:56:36.677+0000    done
2017-12-21T04:56:36.686+0000    checking for collection data in /tmp/mydb/coll2.bson
2017-12-21T04:56:36.686+0000    reading metadata for sqladmin.coll2 from /tmp/mydb/coll2.metadata.json
2017-12-21T04:56:36.699+0000    restoring sqladmin.coll2 from /tmp/mydb/coll2.bson
2017-12-21T04:56:36.760+0000    no indexes to restore
2017-12-21T04:56:36.760+0000    finished restoring sqladmin.coll2 (2 documents)
2017-12-21T04:56:36.760+0000    done
```

### Check the collections

```
> use sqladmin
switched to db sqladmin
> show collections
coll1
coll2
```

Comment: Why not just run the command once and specify --nsInclude multiple times, once for each namespace?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky thank you for pointing that out, it works fabulously!

Answer (score -2):

> How do I restore multiple collections at once in mongodb

if you want to `restore` multiple `collections` of dumps at a time from your `MongoDB` dumps then simply use in mongo shell the below command.

```
mongorestore --verbose C:\locationofdumpsFiles
```

**Note:-** You must sure you are running the above command in **BIN** directory of MongoDB Server.

Suppose that in my environment the MongoDB installation location is such as

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin
```

So, i will first open the 'command prompt' and go to the `BIN` location of the `MongoDB`. Because `mongorestore` shell is reside inside of `MongoDB BIN` foleder.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>
```

Then run the command such as

```
 C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongorestore --verbose C:\locationofdumpsFiles
```